# How can I get a service to request a restart?

Tags: .net, windows, service

How can I have a Windows Service request a restart?  I know about `Environment.Exit(1)` in conjunction with the Recovery Options service settings, but what if the service genuinely errors?

**Background:**

We have a bunch of Windows services that use autonomous components as part of our SOA architecture.  We want to restart the services when the autonomous components update, but we don't want to be limited to two restarts (releases) a day, and we don't want the service to restart indefinitely if there is a genuine error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got around it doing this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process.Start("cmd", "/c net stop \"Service1\" && net start \"Service1\"");
```

It appears that `Process.Start()` either does not create a child process, or that child processes are not killed when the parent dies.

Note that the user the process runs as will have to have permissions to start and stop the process.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a number of self-updating services that use this technique. I found that relying on the recovery options was not ideal, since it often leaves sysadmins the feeling that your service is bombing out on their machines (writing to the event log that service recovery is taking place due to an unexpected service stop).

What I did in my case, which was admittedly hacky but effective, was to launch a specifically crafted executable under an account that is created during the service's install. The account is denied logon rights, and has control over our specific services only (using icacals or equivalent to grant service control permissions). The executable is launched, which communicates with the service using a number of predefined `OnCustomCommand` [service commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand.aspx) that tell the service that it has been updated, that it needs to finish up what its doing, and shut down as soon as it can. The executable waits around for a given time, and once the service has stopped, it moves around the binaries, and performs a number of other custom steps, then starts the service back up, and exits.

I'm sure there are cleaner ways to do this, but after failing to come up with anything cleaner after looking for a few hours I decided that this would work in our case. I haven't had any issues with this in the years it's been in place on a large number of computers, except for the occasional permissions problems due to admins messing with the user account that the executable runs under.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  Very useful for environments where tight user account control is a requirement.